# MySQL multicolumn unique indexing regardless of column

Tags: mysql, indexing, unique-constraint, database-indexes, unique-index

Simple table structure:
id_1 int,
id_2 int,

This is a simple relational table creating a relationship between users. id_1 and id_2 will always be user_ids that exist in another table. I'm trying to create an indexing such that no pair of user_ids can exist in this table more than once, regardless of which column which id is in. For instance given user ids: 1 and 2, if we have a record of:
1,2

Then the record:
2,1 should be considered a duplicate.

All my attempts at unique indexing do not operate in this way since they are column specific. Is there a way to structure this or must it be done with stored procedures or something similar?

Comment: You'll need triggers for this sort of thing. But in general, a table where `id_1` and `id_2` are interchangeable usually means a design problem, and you're setting yourself up for some painful `JOIN` logic once you start querying with the table.

Comment: Similar question: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22085/unique-combination-key-mysql

Answer (score 1):

If I were you and I had to go this way (+1 to Ed Gibbs saying you probably have a design problem) In my code that inserts into MySQL I would always have id_1 < id_2.  So if you have access to your application and you can have it always make id_1 < id_2 you won't have any issues.